# Is there a way to switch to tree view in Nautilus 3.5?

Tags: nautilus, 12.10

Is there a way to switch to tree view in Nautilus in Ubuntu 12.10?

I tried `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state side-pane-view "tree"`, but received a response `No such key 'side-pane-view'`. Did it become obsolete or I'm just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tree view feature has been removed in Nautilus 3.5. You can now only choose between Icon view and List view as a result of this.

Comment: Seems like a bone-headed move!

Comment: Haha. GNOME devs are awesome like that. :-)